# Discord.JS: How to get first channel of a guild?

Tags: node.js, discord.js

I am creating a Discord bot. I want to create invite by guild ID. Creating invite needs a channel. I want to bot to select the first channel. How can I do this?

I used this but did not work:

```js
guild.channels[Object.keys(guild.channels)[0]]
//returns undefined
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you mean first by position, you can look the channels up by type and position using the guild channels collection.

```
const channel = guild.channels.filter(c => c.type === 'text').find(x => x.position == 0);
```

Answer (score 6):

for v12 try

```
var chx = guild.channels.cache.filter(chx => chx.type === "text").find(x => x.position === 0);
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what you're meaning by first channel, but you could use this :

```
const randomChannel = (guild) => {
    guild.channels.random().then(channel => {
        if (channel.type === 'text') return channel;
        else return randomChannel(guild);
    }
}
```

Comment: This is not what the user asked for, he wanted to access the channel that appears highest in the list of channels on the left side, not a random channel.

Answer (score 0):

To get a channel to create an invite you should probably only use ones where the Bot has permissions in, eg:

```
 const invitechannels = guild.channels.filter(c=> c.permissionsFor(guild.me).has('CREATE_INSTANT_INVITE'));
 invitechannels.random().createInvite()
     .then(invite=> console.log('Create Invite:\n' + invite.code))
```

Alternatively you could also check for existing invites:

```
guild.fetchInvites()
    .then(invites => console.log('Found Invites:\n' + invites.map(invite => invite.code).join('\n')))
```

Answer (score 0):

Each channel has a `calculatedPosition` property, which you can use to get the first channel.

```js
const channel = Array.from(guild.channels).sort((a,b) => a.calculatedPosition - b.calculatedPosition)[0];
```

Alright let's break down what is happening in the above code:

```js
Array.from(guild.channels) //returns an Array of GuildChannels (Textchannels and Voicechannels)
.sort((a,b) => a.calculatedPosition - b.calculatedPosition) //sorts the elements in the collection by their calculatedPosition property in ascending order and returns the array
[0] //returns the first element of the array
```

Answer (score 0):

For Discord.js v13 try:

```js
var chx = guild.channels.cache.filter(chx => chx.type === "GUILD_TEXT").find(x => x.position === 0);
```

Use "GUILD_TEXT" instead of "text".

For multiple types use this:

```js
const _arr = ["GUILD_TEXT", "GUILD_NEWS", "UNKNOWN"];
var chx = guild.channels.cache.filter(chx => _arr.includes(chx.type)).keys());
```

More about channels' types read here:
https://discord.js.org/#/docs/discord.js/stable/class/GuildChannel?scrollTo=type